# How to use the continue in a loop if variable is empty in Powershell 2.0?

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach, powershell-2.0

I need some advice in using the continue statement in my script.

My script searches for specific backup files in my backup folder and then creates an sql command to restore that specific backup.

If it can't find the backup my script crashes. So what I need is a continue in my loop if the variable is empty. How is that correctly defined?

```
if ($specificmarketbackupfile -eq "")
        {
            continue
        }
```

this didn't work out ,so what do I need? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try Test-Path or the Contains. Test-Path should be the best route though.

```
If (!(Test-Path $specificmarketbackupfile))
   {
      Commands Here
   }
```

What this will do is return a boolean True or False to whether or not it sees the file / directory defined.